# parallelize calls with async/await in recursive method in Node.JS (ES7)

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, parallel-processing, async-await

I have the following method of a class in Node.JS 8.6.0:

```
async urlProcess(nodo,nivel,topenivel,conf){
try{  
  // some exiting conditions and  
  // some synchronous code around here
  // ..... 

   let DOM = await this.getDocumentData(url); //this methos returns Promise
   if(DOM){

    // More sequential code ,we have an array of URLs in let sons;
   // and finally we get this:

    // == SEQUENTIAL SOLUTION == //

    // for(let  urlHija of sons){
    //   await this.urlProcess(urlHija,nivel+1,topenivel,conf);
    // }

    // == PARALLEL SOLUTION == //
    let promises = [];

    for(let urlHija of sons){
      promises.push(this.urlProcess(urlHija,nivel+1,topenivel,conf));
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);

    return 0;

  }else
    return 0;

}catch(err){
  throw err;
}
}
```

When I measure the performance of two solutions what I get is that the sequential one is faster, so I think that parallelization is not working for some reason.
The way I measure times is like this:

```
async start(nivel,topenivel,payload) {
try {
  let nodo = this.arbol.getRaiz();
  console.time("performance");
  await this.urlProcess(nodo, nivel, topenivel, payload)
  console.timeEnd("performance");
  return 0;
}catch(err){
  throw err;
}
};
```

Comment: how do you measure the performance? And did you check your network traffic? maybe you start too many paralell requests and they block each other. Or maybe you hit some limitations on the backend. Hard to tell with that little information.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, I added more information about measuring timing with console.time(). I can tell it's not about back-end limitations or network issues.